# How do I handle obtaining an OAuth authorization grant in my Python Script after a redirect?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, authorization

I need to write a Python script to run an OAuth 2.0 client side flow. In the flow, I need to have the user run the Python script, have the browser open to log in and grant access, then obtain the Authorization Grant to trade in for the Access Token and continue the flow. I have been searching and haven't found a good answer on how to do this as most examples don't involve an actual OAuth login or require copy/paste. Is there a clean way to seamlessly integrate the flow into my Python code for local use?

I have briefly tried threading and http to create a localhost server to obtain the request, have experimented with flask, and have tried looking to see if creating a protocol handler could be of help. I had some success with all of these and am able to get through the flow, but still can't seem to pull the Authorization code from the redirect uri. The script will be run internally and won't be distributed, but needs to at least be clean enough that copy/pasting doesn't have to happen.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will create a temporary localhost and allow the scraping of the Authorization Grant from the URL along with retrieving and returning the Access Token.

```
import requests
import threading
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import webbrowser

access_token = None

# Simple HTTP request handler to capture the authorization code
class AuthorizationHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    authorization_code = None

    def do_GET(self):
        global access_token
        if self.path.startswith("/oauth-callback?"):
            # Extract the authorization code from the query parameters
            authorization_code = self.path.split("&code=")[1]

            # Display the authorization code
            print("Authorization Code:", self.authorization_code)

            # Send a response to the browser
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(b"<h1>Authorization Code Received</h1>")

            # Obtain OAuth Client Access Token
            headers = {'accept':'*/*'}
            parameters = {'client_id':'{{Client_ID}}','client_secret':'{{Client_Secret}}','access_code':authorization_code}
            response = requests.get("{{tokenURL}}",headers=headers,params=parameters)
            print(response.text)
            token = response.text

            # Log in using Access Token from OAuth
            headers = {'accept':'*/*','Content-Type':'application/json'}
            body = {'token':token}
            response = requests.post("{{loginURL}}",headers=headers,json=body)
            print(response.text)
            json_response = response.json()
            access_token= json_response["token"]

            # Exit the function after obtaining the token
            raise SystemExit

# Start a temporary HTTP server in a separate thread
def start_temp_server():
    server = HTTPServer(("localhost", 8000), AuthorizationHandler)
    server.serve_forever()

# Example usage
authorization_url = "{{AuthorizationURL}}"

# Start the temporary server in a separate thread
server_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_temp_server)
server_thread.start()

# Open the authorization URL in the default web browser
webbrowser.open(authorization_url)

server_thread.join()
```